# Heroku: What's this configuration error related to the application.prod.conf key?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework

I'm in the process of learning to deploy a Playframework application in Heroku and after building it using Heroku CLI I'm getting the following start up error:

```
2019-09-27T16:37:48.855277+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `target/universal/stage/bin/myapp -Dhttp.port=${PORT} -Dconfig.resource=${PLAY_CONF_FILE}`
2019-09-27T16:37:51.154913+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2019-09-27T16:37:51.348360+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2019-09-27T16:37:52.538427+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-27T16:37:52.447980+00:00 app[web.1]: Oops, cannot start the server.
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450270+00:00 app[web.1]: Configuration error: Configuration error[ @ file:/app/target/universal/stage/conf/: 2: Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'application.prod.conf' (if you intended 'application.prod.conf' to be part of a key or string value, try enclosing the key or value in double quotes)]
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450489+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:171)
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450570+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.api.Configuration$.load(Configuration.scala:109)
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450644+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.readServerConfigSettings(ProdServerStart.scala:111)
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450715+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.start(ProdServerStart.scala:48)
2019-09-27T16:37:52.450821+00:00 app[web.1]: at play.core.server.ProdServerStart$.main(ProdServerStart.scala:31)
```

Saying basically that `Key 'application.conf' may not be followed by token: 'application.prod.conf'` What does that mean? Is this a Heroku error or a Playframework error?

My `app.js` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "MyApp web application",
  "image": "heroku/scala",
  "addons": [ "heroku-postgresql" ],
  "repository": "https://github.com/username/myapp/tree/heroku",
  "success_url": "/",
  "env": {
    "BUILDPACK_URL": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git",
    "PLAY_CONF_FILE": "application.prod.conf",
    "PLAY_APP_SECRET": "changeme",
    "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID": "",
    "FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET": "",
    "GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID": "",
    "GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: have you seen https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support ?

Comment: Can you share your project? I'm not really familiar with heroku, but I was able to deploy a vanilla play-scala-seed project. It seems to be a problem how your env variables are inserted into application.conf or something similar.